# Heyting and Lugano

Tags: biographical-details, mathematicians

I read in Wikipedia that Arend Heyting, logician, died in Lugano while all the biographies focus on his career in Amsterdam and [nearby](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Heyting/).

Do we know if he lived in Lugano or not, and why died there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A.S. Troelstra, [Levensbericht A. Heyting](https://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/levensberichten/PE00000845.pdf), in: Jaarboek, 1980, Amsterdam, pp. 172-175:

> Hoewel hij zich na zijn hartaanval wel ontzien moest, genoot hij toch een redelijke gezondheid tot vlak voor zijn dood. Hij overleed tijdens een vakantie te Lugano, Zwitserland, op 9 juli 1980, na een kortstondig ziekbed.

With Google translator:

> He died while on vacation in Lugano, Switzerland, on July 9 1980, after a short illness.

Comment: The comparison of the lengths of respective texts in Dutch and in English drive me to the conclusion that Dutch is a very talkative language.